# Get list of key names based on values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I would like to get a list of key names based on a value I check.

This is what I have.

```js
const data = {
  "DE": "ARUN",
  "HI": "ARUN",
  "PR": "ARUN",
  "TX": "ARUN",
  "MA": "ARUN",
  "MD": "CHARLES,BRANDON,DAVID,ARUN",
  "IA": "ARUN",
  "ME": "ARUN",
  "ID": "ARUN",
  "MI": "ARUN",
  "UT": "ARUN",
  "MN": "ARUN",
  "MO": "ARUN",
  "IL": "ARUN",
  "IN": "ARUN",
  "MS": "ARUN",
  "MT": "ARUN",
  "AK": "ARUN",
  "AL": "ARUN",
  "VA": "ARUN",
  "AR": "ARUN",
  "AS": "ARUN",
  "VI": "ARUN",
  "NC": "ARUN",
  "ND": "ARUN",
  "NE": "ARUN",
  "RI": "ARUN",
  "AZ": "ARUN",
  "NH": "ARUN",
  "NJ": "ARUN",
  "VT": "ARUN",
  "NM": "ARUN",
  "FL": "ARUN",
  "NV": "ARUN",
  "WA": "ARUN",
  "NY": "ARUN",
  "SC": "ARUN",
  "SD": "ARUN",
  "WI": "ARUN",
  "OH": "ARUN",
  "GA": "ARUN",
  "OK": "ARUN",
  "CA": "ARUN",
  "WV": "ARUN",
  "WY": "ARUN",
  "OR": "ARUN",
  "KS": "ARUN",
  "CM": "ARUN",
  "CO": "ARUN",
  "GU": "ARUN",
  "KY": "ARUN",
  "CT": "ARUN",
  "PA": "ARUN",
  "LA": "ARUN",
  "TN": "ARUN",
  "DC": "ARUN"
}

const name = 'BRANDON'

const newMappedData = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
  return {
    [key]: data[key].split(',')
  }
})

const filteredData = newMappedData.filter(item => Object.values(item).includes(name))


console.log(filteredData)
```

In the above example, when we enter 'BRANDON', the result should only be `['MD']` and if 'ARUN', it should give me `['DE', 'HI', 'PR',...]`

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `includes` you don't even need to `split`. Also you don't need to use `map` to create a new array:

```js
const data = {
  "DE": "ARUN",
  "HI": "ARUN",
  "PR": "ARUN",
  "TX": "ARUN",
  "MA": "ARUN",
  "MD": "CHARLES,BRANDON,DAVID,ARUN",
  "IA": "ARUN",
  "ME": "ARUN",
  "ID": "ARUN",
  "MI": "ARUN",
  "UT": "ARUN",
  "MN": "ARUN",
  "MO": "ARUN",
  "IL": "ARUN",
  "IN": "ARUN",
  "MS": "ARUN",
  "MT": "ARUN",
  "AK": "ARUN",
  "AL": "ARUN",
  "VA": "ARUN",
  "AR": "ARUN",
  "AS": "ARUN",
  "VI": "ARUN",
  "NC": "ARUN",
  "ND": "ARUN",
  "NE": "ARUN",
  "RI": "ARUN",
  "AZ": "ARUN",
  "NH": "ARUN",
  "NJ": "ARUN",
  "VT": "ARUN",
  "NM": "ARUN",
  "FL": "ARUN",
  "NV": "ARUN",
  "WA": "ARUN",
  "NY": "ARUN",
  "SC": "ARUN",
  "SD": "ARUN",
  "WI": "ARUN",
  "OH": "ARUN",
  "GA": "ARUN",
  "OK": "ARUN",
  "CA": "ARUN",
  "WV": "ARUN",
  "WY": "ARUN",
  "OR": "ARUN",
  "KS": "ARUN",
  "CM": "ARUN",
  "CO": "ARUN",
  "GU": "ARUN",
  "KY": "ARUN",
  "CT": "ARUN",
  "PA": "ARUN",
  "LA": "ARUN",
  "TN": "ARUN",
  "DC": "ARUN"
}

const name = 'BRANDON'

const filteredData = Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key].includes(name))

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the keys by checking the splitted string.

```js
const
    getKeys = value => Object.keys(data).filter(k => data[k].split(',').includes(value)),
    data = { DE: "ARUN", HI: "ARUN", PR: "ARUN", TX: "ARUN", MA: "ARUN", MD: "CHARLES,BRANDON,DAVID,ARUN", IA: "ARUN", ME: "ARUN", ID: "ARUN", MI: "ARUN", UT: "ARUN", MN: "ARUN", MO: "ARUN", IL: "ARUN", IN: "ARUN", MS: "ARUN", MT: "ARUN", AK: "ARUN", AL: "ARUN", VA: "ARUN", AR: "ARUN", AS: "ARUN", VI: "ARUN", NC: "ARUN", ND: "ARUN", NE: "ARUN", RI: "ARUN", AZ: "ARUN", NH: "ARUN", NJ: "ARUN", VT: "ARUN", NM: "ARUN", FL: "ARUN", NV: "ARUN", WA: "ARUN", NY: "ARUN", SC: "ARUN", SD: "ARUN", WI: "ARUN", OH: "ARUN", GA: "ARUN", OK: "ARUN", CA: "ARUN", WV: "ARUN", WY: "ARUN", OR: "ARUN", KS: "ARUN", CM: "ARUN", CO: "ARUN", GU: "ARUN", KY: "ARUN", CT: "ARUN", PA: "ARUN", LA: "ARUN", TN: "ARUN", DC: "ARUN" };

console.log(getKeys('BRANDON'));
console.log(getKeys('ARUN'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```